# Github UPDATE / OVERWRITE existing asset of a release

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-api, github-actions

I have a asset in my latest release which I want to overwrite.
I am using Github Api to get upload url of latest release assets (username and token is optional here).

```
upload_url=$(curl -sL userName:token https://api.github.com/repos/actions/checkout/releases/latest | jq -r '.upload_url')
```

This can be used to upload asset to that url but if there is an existing asset with same name then it throws error.

So I want a way to update or delete that asset...
Github api has endpoints([update](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#update-a-release-asset), [delete](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#delete-a-release-asset)) to do it but can you help me with these curl commands? how do I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want a way to update or delete that asset...

[GitHub CLI gh 2.5.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.5.0) now has [`gh release delete-asset`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_delete-asset), from [PR 4416](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/4416) and [issue 4258](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/4258)

```
gh release delete-asset <tag> <asset-name> [flags]
```

It wraps the appropriate [GitHub API endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/releases#delete-a-release-asset);

```
DELETE /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/assets/{asset_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

This [github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/yet-another-upload-release-asset-action) doest it with upload_url of draft or release